# Why some things are traded in an exchange while others are traded OTC

Tags: trading, stock-exchanges

What is the reason some instruments like CFDs and FX are traded as OTC instruments while others (stocks, futures,options) are traded in an exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All securities must be [registered](https://www.sec.gov/answers/regis33.htm) with the SEC.

Securities are [defined](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/77b) as

> (1) The term “security” means any note, stock, treasury stock,
>   security future, security-based swap, bond, debenture, evidence of
>   indebtedness, certificate of interest or participation in any
>   profit-sharing agreement, collateral-trust certificate,
>   preorganization certificate or subscription, transferable share,
>   investment contract, voting-trust certificate, certificate of deposit
>   for a security, fractional undivided interest in oil, gas, or other
>   mineral rights, any put, call, straddle, option, or privilege on any
>   security, certificate of deposit, or group or index of securities
>   (including any interest therein or based on the value thereof), or any
>   put, call, straddle, option, or privilege entered into on a national
>   securities exchange relating to foreign currency, or, in general, any
>   interest or instrument commonly known as a “security”, or any
>   certificate of interest or participation in, temporary or interim
>   certificate for, receipt for, guarantee of, or warrant or right to
>   subscribe to or purchase, any of the foregoing.

thus currencies are not defined as securities.

While OTC transactions of securities is not outright forbidden, there are numerous regulations issued by the SEC as a result of the [1943 Exchange Act](http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/securities_exchange_act_of_1934) and others that make this difficult and/or costly.

Many other securities are [exempted](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/77c) from registration thus trade in a way that could be called OTC.

Different countries have variances upon US law but are very similar.

Any security could be traded OTC, but law prohibits it expressly or in such a way to make it relatively expensive; further, stock options are so tightly regulated that expiration dates, expiration intervals, strike intervals, and minimum ticks are all set by the authorities.